# Money is no object

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, économie

We have this expression in English like "money is no object", it means you will spend however much necessary to get what you want.

It does sound like a weird and abstract thing to say in English (although it would be commonly understood), so I was wondering if a literal translation like "l'argent n'est pas un obstacle" will still make sense to an average French speaker.

Or is there some better expression in French which I should be using instead to convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your proposal, *L'argent n'est pas un obstacle*, is correct and will be understood.

You could also use

> L'argent n'est pas un problème
>
> Le coût n'est pas un problème

Or, if you can rephrase, you could use *avoir carte blanche* or *donner un chèque en blanc*.

Comment: L'argent (ou le coût) n'est pas *le* problème. Le *le* insiste alors plus sur la difficulté du choix de *l'objet* et de sa valeur affective ou mercantile que de sa valeur fiduciaire

Comment: @cl-r "Le" implies something very different, namely that there **is** a specific problem about the purchase you want to perform (e.g. base availability, difficult choice), but that it is not money or price. The original sentence is a simple statement about how much the buyer is willing to spend (i.e. a limitless amount).

Answer (score 1):

You could try

> Le coût/prix est sans importance.

But unless you are a Russian oligarch, you probably mean

> Le coût/prix est secondaire".